# Quadrature over three Euler Angles for orientation averaging

Tags: molecular-dynamics, mathematical-modeling, quantum-dynamics

Does anybody know about an accurate quadrature rule over *three* Euler angles $\theta, \phi, \chi$?
I am trying to calculate the average value of an arbitrary function $f(\theta, \phi, \chi)$ for a given probability distribution $\rho(\theta, \phi, \chi)$:

$$
\langle f\rangle_{\rho} = \int_0^{2\pi} d\chi \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi\int_0^{\pi} \sin\theta d\theta f(\theta, \phi, \chi)\rho(\theta, \phi, \chi) \approx \sum_{l} w_l g(\theta_l, \phi_l, \chi_l)
$$
where $f(\theta, \phi, \chi)$ is *not*  sum-of-products of single angle-coordinate functions. $w_l$ are quadrature weights and $(\theta_l, \phi_l, \chi_l)$ represents a single grid point. $g(\theta, \phi, \chi) =  \sin\theta f(\theta, \phi, \chi)\rho(\theta, \phi, \chi)$ and an appropriate quadrature weight-function is implicitly included in $f$.

Such an integration is sometimes needed in orientation averaged calculations of material/molecule's properties.

What we can assume about $\rho(\theta, \phi, \chi)$ is that it is a linear combination of the products of the Wigner D-matrices: $\rho(\theta, \phi, \chi) = \sum_{K,K'} c_{KK'} D^{(J)}_{KM}(\theta, \phi, \chi)D^{(J')}_{K'M'}(\theta, \phi, \chi)$.

So to sum up. It seems there is a need for a simple quadrature scheme for integration over three Euler angles: $\theta, \phi, \chi$.

- **Update:**

Ways around the need for explicit three-Euler angle $\theta, \phi, \chi$ quadrature:

1. Expanding $f(\theta, \phi, \chi)$ in the Wigner matrices basis is one way of proceeding here. The appropriate integrals can be calculated analytically. But for some functions $f(\theta, \phi, \chi)$ this method is very inefficient, as the Wigner expansion has many terms.
2. Another possibility, if we are dealing with a quantum system, is to solve the Schroedinger equation for wavefunctions in three separate system-fixed embeddings of the coordinate frame. Then one can choose the system-fixed z-axis to be the axis in the system that we want to quantify (average over). In such a case only $\theta, \phi$ are needed.
   *The down-side* to this approach is that one needs to repeat calculations for three independent embeddings, which for some embeddings and some external potentials can be very unnatural. In the case of rotational dynamics problems the complete symmetric-top basis sets guarantee accuracy of the solutions regardless of the embedding chosen. Rotational wavefunction representations among different embeddings differ only by the coefficients. In good embeddings the rotational wavefunction can be reprsented compactly in the basis, but if the embedding is poor, often many basis functions are needed. In the case of problems which add coupling of rotational degrees of freedom to some other internal or external degrees of freedom, the choice of embedding is often critical for quick convergence of the variational procedure.

Comment: +1. Nice first question Emil! I have also advertised it here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1878/computational-science. You can draw more attention to it by hovering your mouse on the question there, and then pressing the star.

Comment: Do you really need **three** angles? If you have a system, then one axis is already fixed, and you're left with quadrature on a sphere which is a well-known problem that has several accurate rules.

Comment: Thanks, however I'm not sure what you mean by one axis being fixed. To determine the orientation of a body which is not linear three angles are required. The $f$ function is often represented through rational functions of the elements of the rotation matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix) - it is a function of three Euler angles. For a linear rotating body Lebedev quadratures are good. I'm searching for a generalization to non-linear rotating bodies.

Comment: @EmilZak I mean that if you have an input orientation, then one axis is already fixed implicitly. You only need two angles to compute the rotational average..?

Comment: @EmilZak I see what Susi is saying. If you have some starting structure and just want different rotations from that initial structure, you should just need two angles.

Comment: In case integration of the three Euler angles is really what you need, I haven't done it myself but if I am stuck at this for too long, I will try the inner 2D integral over $(\theta, \phi)$ first with the available quadrature-on-sphere methods like Lebedev quadrature as you mentioned, and then do the integral over $\chi$ with the usual one-variable quadrature. The potential downside of this technique is that we probably can't guarantee that the function of $\chi$ resulting from the $(\theta,\phi)$ integration is well-behaving enough for the subsequent quadrature to work with few points.

Comment: @EmilZak was I right to move the final sentence to before the update section? Also, can you update the question with some information about what type of research you did on this, prior to asking the question? Maybe your prior research was just searching "quadrature for function 3 Euler angles", or maybe you asked on a different forum, or maybe you looked in the book "Numerical Recipes for FORTRAN", or another book on numerical recipes/techniques? Was it only the Google search? If so, what did you find?

Comment: These two papers: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.03353.pdf 
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01630560903163508
address the problem of integration over the SO(3) group.

Comment: You might get more answers if you explain the question in a bit more detail, especially the definition of *quadrature* (in this context).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any exact methods, but [`quadpy`](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) is a really good place to start, and possibly ask the related question there.

Not really an answer, but more of a *hint*.